# hiding downoad/share button in default controls of html5 <video> on mobile and otherwise

Tags: html

Can I remove the default share/download button that comes in default controls  on hover of html5  tag , esp in mobile?
my code is like:

```
<video id="#video1" controls autoplay src="playback.mp4"></video>
```

I also did in css something like `video::-webkit-media-controls-panel{background: white; opacity: 1}`, but i could not go inside this, i mean doing

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-panel *:nth-last-of-type(2){background: red !important}
```

didnot work because there is nothing 'inside' the media-controls-panel in html.

Pls suggest solution. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

try with this remove **control** from video tag

```
<video id="#video1" autoplay src="playback.mp4"></video>
```